# Конкатенация в функции Swift

Tags: swift

пишу функцию для конкатенации двух строк в функции, что делаю не так?

```
func getConcatenation() -> (string1: String, string2: String) {
let string1 = "Writing Swift code "
let string2 = "is interactive and fun"
let results = string1 + string2
return results
}

print(getConcatenation())
```

Answer (score 0):

Примерно так нужно сделать

```
func getConcatenation(string1: String, string2: String) -> String {
    let results = string1 + string2
    return results
}

print(getConcatenation(string1:"Writing Swift code ", string2:"is interactive and fun"))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
func getConcatenation() -> (String) {
    let string1 = "Writing Swift code "
    let string2 = "is interactive and fun"
    let results = string1 + string2
    return results
}

print(getConcatenation())
```